# Greater than or equal to in Custom number format

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, rounding, number-formatting

I'm looking to custom format this values but when my result is 15.0 or 14.9 the formula doesn't work. I've tried to place <= or =< but the custom number format doesn't recognize it.

Here is my current formula.

```
[>15.0]0.0[color 50]"▲";[<14.9]0.0[red]"▼";0.0
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use:

```
[>=15.0]0.0[color 50]"▲";[<=14.9]0.0[red]"▼";0.0
```

[image]

[image]

---

### update

try:

```
[>=15.0]0.0[color 50]"▲";[<=14.9999999999999]0.0[red]"▼";0.0
```

[image]

Comment: When I need 15.0 or 14.9, the formatting color doesn't apply

Comment: Actually it does work for 15.0 but not for 14.9

Comment: I have updated some pictures were you can find how I'm using the formula and where it doesn't apply

Comment: @mau answer updated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239139/discussion-between-mau-and-player0).

Comment: Ok, Ill text you